# The work of mathematicians in physics and experimental labs

Tags: mathematics, application, physics, engineering

I am especially interested in a course in a well-known and renowned experimental physics laboratory. When applying, among the questions they expect you to answer, they ask how I think my knowledge could be beneficial in the program offered (which is a general program in which projects are assigned to students, but they are not previously predetermined). Among the areas of possible choice (all experimental except this last one) I have chosen theoretical physics.

I wanted to know the type of work that mathematicians usually do in projects in experimental laboratories or similar where the accepted profiles are engineers, computer scientists, physicists and mathematicians to know how I could apply my knowledge for the benefit of both applying for the program and to do the best job possible in it.

I am currently a mathematics undergraduate and I am eligible to apply for the program.

Thank you very much for your time and responses in advance.

P.s: I originally posted the question in MSE, but was advised to better post it here in ASE.

Comment: An undergraduate is pretty much a blank slate. You could be asked to do any number of things. I would expect you could do some hands-on work (and would encourage you to), maybe some programming of data acquisition or data analysis tools, maybe some simulations, who knows?